# NivoSlider - Link after slideshow is shown + fade to white?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I am using the Nivoslider script for a project of mine. Basically I'm needing to tweak the slider a little to make it do what I want it to do! I need it to do two things:

1. How can I make it re-direct to a new page after the slideshow is finished? I can make it stop after it cycles through, but I need it to automatically redirect to another page of the site after my images have been shown. I assume this is through using nivosliders function `lastslide`.
2. Is there any way of making nivoSlider fade to white, then to the slide instead of crossfading? I tried to add a "white" slide in between the slides, but you can't specify seperate timing for the slides, so it stayed on this "white slide" for 4 seconds, I need it to fade to white for about 0.5 seconds then fade in the next slide.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
        directionNavHide: true, // Only show on hover
        controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav: true, // Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity: 0.8, // Universal caption opacity
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){
            var $slider = $('#slider img');
            $slider.css('opacity',0);
            $('#preloader').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $slider.animate({'opacity':1}, 500);
            });
            } // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, just add this line in your afterLoad function()

`window.location = "http://google.com"`